# How to list all open files and dir using java?

Tags: java, applet

How to get the all open files,doc,and dir details in java applet or console?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "open files"?

Comment: I need open file details........... It means, After you open "a.doc " and "b.txt" and any one folder. In that time when I execute java program,. Output shown lik "a.doc","b.txt" and one folder are open........

Comment: Still unclear: by "open", do you mean opened by the user on the desktop via Word or Windows Explorer? Or by the java program?

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that. There are security restrictions on Applet API that will prevent you from accessing low level I/O functions that operates on files.

Even though you might end up accessing individual files (if manipulate your apple security policy on the running machine), access to **all open directory and files** require higher privileges that you don't have in JVM.

Comment: I need open file details........... It means, after you open "a.doc " and "b.txt" and any one folder. In that time when I execute java program,. Output shown lik "a.doc","b.txt" and one folder are open........ –

Comment: This is not possible, as Pablo explained.